# Creating complex documents from separate files

Tags: include, preamble

I have multiple documents (`file1.tex`, `file2.tex`, etc.) and one main file (let's call it `main.tex`).

I would like to build a complex document that contains all `file_i.tex` files. I tried this (according to some online guide):

```
\documentstyle{report}
...
\begin{document}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
...
\end{document}
```

I tried include command too, but I keep getting "LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble."
What am I doing wrong?

Bonus question:
I have headings structure in all my files like this:

File1:

```
1. Heading1
 1.1. Subheading1
 1.2. Subheading2
etc
```

File2:

```
1. Heading2
 1.1. Subheading1
 1.2. Subheading2
etc
```

When I build my document as described below. I want my heading to be updated like this:

```
1. Heading1
 1.1. Subheading1
 ...
2. Heading2
 2.1. Subheading2
 ...
```

And then generate index. Is there some easy way how to do this in LaTeX (I believe there is, when it was designed to do this but I cant seem to figure out the right command/structure).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you `input` a file, that other file must not contain a preamble or other header/footer material, because it will be included *verbatim* at the point of `\input`.

Therefore, you should strip your `file_i` documents of their TeX header and footer, and leave only the content itself.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just one more thing - in which file can I use "usepackage" commands? It works when I delete them all, but wherever I put them, I get an error. thx

Comment: Only in the main document.

Comment: Error: LaTeX2e command \usepackage in LaTeX 2.09 document (this is what I get when I put it in the main text file)

Comment: Use `\documentclass` instead of `\documentstyle`. The latter is an older form which triggers a compatibility mode in LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 7):

You actually **can** use `\input` on files that are complete compilable LaTeX files (with a preamble) if you use [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) in the main document.  There are numerous examples on this site, but below I have used [the `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) to make a self contained example that shows how this can be used.

To answer your other question, assuming that you are referring to a table of contents rather than an index, you can do this by including `\tableofcontents` in the main document. If you want to also have hyper links in the table of contents you need to also include [the `hyperref` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/).

The code below yields the desired structure with click able links:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to generate the file containing the necessary information for the `\tableofcontents`, and the second to actually produce the Table of Contents.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{filecontents}%
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.tex}
    \documentclass{report}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Heading1}
        \section{Subheading1}
        \section{Subheading2}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.tex}
    \documentclass{report}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Heading2}
        \section{Subheading1}
        \section{Subheading2}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \input{file1}
    \input{file2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [nneonneo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21305/) already said, there is no need for preambles in included files. In case you want to realize more complex document structures with `input` or `include` commands on two or more levels you can also consider to use the `import` package ([CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/import)) to include files using a **relative path**.

- `\import{〈full_path〉}{〈file〉}`
- `\subimport{〈path_extension〉}{〈file〉}`
- `\includefrom{〈full_path〉}{〈file〉}`
- `\subincludefrom{〈path_extension〉}{〈file〉}`